# How do I play multiple audio files multiple times in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I have 5 audio files a,b,c,d,e

When the user clicks the play button it should play audio files from a to e one after another.

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    Button play,stop;

    MediaPlayer mp;
    MediaPlayer mp2;
    MediaPlayer mp3;
    MediaPlayer mp4;
    MediaPlayer mp5;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        play = findViewById(R.id.play);
        stop = findViewById(R.id.stop);
    }




    public void Play(View view){
        StopPlaying();
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.a);
        mp2= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.b);
        mp3= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.c);
        mp4= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.d);
        mp5= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.e);
        int i = 0;
        while (i<10){
            i++;
            mp.start();
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp2.start();
                    mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp3.start();
                            mp3.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                    mp4.start();
                                    mp4.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                            mp5.start();
                                            mp5.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            
        }
    }





    
    
    

    private void StopPlaying(){

        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }


        if (mp2 != null) {
            mp2.stop();
            mp2.release();
            mp2 = null;
        }

        if (mp3 != null) {
            mp3.stop();
            mp3.release();
            mp3 = null;
        }


        if (mp4 != null) {
            mp4.stop();
            mp4.release();
            mp4 = null;
        }


        if (mp5 != null) {
            mp5.stop();
            mp5.release();
            mp5 = null;
        }


    }

    public void Stop(View viw){
        mp.stop();
        mp2.stop();
        mp3.stop();
        mp4.stop();
        mp5.stop();
    }




}
```

```html
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#afc3d7"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
         />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
         />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/times"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:inputType="number"
        />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:onClick="Play"
        android:text="Play" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:onClick="Stop"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Stop" />




</LinearLayout>
```

But what I want is it should play them like 10 times,

(after e is played, it should again start from a toe)

like from a toe and then again from a toe and then again.....repeat this 10 times

It's like repeating a song in a music player once it is finished, the only difference is I am repeating multiple audio files in a sequence.

I have tried using for loop and while loop but none of them seem to work...

Here is my code

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Use media player in the below format

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Doing this way you won't have to create 5 different media players. When your first audio file finishes, then in your `onCompleteListener`, just change the DataSource of the media player and start it again

Answer (score 0):

create an array like this :

```
private final int[] resID = { R.raw.chimes, R.raw.chord, R.raw.ding,
R.raw.notify, R.raw.recycle, R.raw.ringin, R.raw.ringout,
R.raw.tada };  
int from,to,times,songPosition,timesPosition=0;
```

and then on click

```
    songPosition = from;

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                            playSong(songPosition);

                }
            });  


     private void playSong(int position) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                    }
                }
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resID[position]);
                mediaPlayer.start();
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                if(timesPosition<times){
                     if(songsPosition<=to){
                          songsPosition = songsPosition + 1;
                          playSong(songsPosition)
                     }else{
                          songPosition = from;
                          timesPosition + timesPosition+1;
                          playSong(songsPosition)
                     }
              }
              }
            });
    }
```